# CSS being interpreted as plain text on other peoples computers, but working on mine

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a home page, and everything was going smoothly. However, whenever I send it to someone else, the CSS doesn't work properly. When I examine the code on their laptop it appears it isn't being registered as code, but rather as plain text. I have included my entire code just in case it is something wrong with another part. For context I have saved it as a .html document on Firefox. There isn't any error when it is loaded, the CSS just doesn't work. I am very new to HTML and CSS so it may be something very simple.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    a:link {
      color: black;
    }
    
    a:visited {
      color: black;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: #327da8;
    }
    
    .name {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-color: black;
      font-family: montserrat;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 360px;
      text-align: left;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: lightgray;
      padding: 27.5px;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    }
    
    a img {
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: block;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      font-family: montserrat;
      font-weight: 150;
    }
    
    body {
      background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/The%20Lost%20Dogs%20Home.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: left top;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: 200px, 600px;
    }
    
    a:hover~.name {
      color: #327da8;
      border-color: #327da8;
    }
    
    img {
      border: 10px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <table style="margin-left:190px;margin-right:auto; margin-top:45px; font-size:20px;">
      <tr>
        <th><a class="navbar" href="PupLove.html">Home</a></th>
        <th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveDonate.html">Donate</a></th>
        <th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveCare.html">How to take care of a dog</a></th>
        <th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveContacts&FAQ's.html">Contacts and FAQ's</a></th>
        <th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveBlog.html">Blog</a></th>
  </nav>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <div>
    <a href="PupLoveNala.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:50px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://www.yourpurebredpuppy.com/dogbreeds/photos-EFGH/goldenretrieversf1.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
    <a class="name" style="margin-left:50px;" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveNala.html">Nala <br><br> Breed: Golden <br> Retriever <br><br> Sex: Female</a></div>

  <div>
    <a href="PupLoveBillie.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:350px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://www.yourpurebredpuppy.com/dogbreeds/photos-EFGH/greatdanesf5.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
    <a class="name" style="margin-left:350px; padding:36.5px" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveBillie.html">Billie <br><br> Breed: Great <br> Dane <br><br> Sex: Male</a></div>

  <div>
    <a href="PupLoveBendi.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:650px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://www.yourpurebredpuppy.com/dogbreeds/photos-AB/australiancattledogsf1.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
    <a class="name" style="margin-left:650px; padding:41px" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveBendi.html">Bendi <br><br> Breed: Blue <br> Heeler <br><br> Sex: Male</a></div>

  <div>
    <a href="PupLoveRufus.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:950px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Bearded_collie_and_a_rope.jpg/640px-Bearded_collie_and_a_rope.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
    <a class="name" style="margin-left:950px; padding:21px" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveRufus.html"><br>Rufus <br><br> Breed: Bearded <br> Collie <br><br> Sex: Male<br>ㅤ</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: I think it may be something with how it is saved. Are there any 'dont's' when saving files in html?

Comment: have you tried taking the styles in a separate style.css file and link it in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: If you can provide a screenshot of the "plain text" display, that might help a lot!

Comment: How are you sending it to other people and how are they then saving it and running it (e.g are you emailing it or dropboxing it or...)?

Comment: How do I upload screenshots in the comments?

Comment: @AHaworth generally I send it through Microsoft teams, whereupon they download it and open it. I've also sent it through discord with the same result.

Comment: Edit your question to upload images rather than try to put them  into comments.

Comment: I added the image now, it should be above the text

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the reason but you have tags that are badly closed,
I have corrected your code saying the standards:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>

<style>
a:link {
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: #327da8;
}

.name {
  font-size:20px;
  color:black;
  font-family:montserrat;
  text-decoration:none; position:absolute;
  margin-top: 360px; text-align:left; border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid; border-color:lightgray;
  padding: 27.5px;
  border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
}

a img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

.navbar {
text-decoration:none; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; font-family:montserrat; font-weight:150;
}

body {
background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/The%20Lost%20Dogs%20Home.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 200px, 600px;
}

a:hover ~ .name { 
color: #327da8; 
border-color: #327da8;
}

img {
border:10px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
<table style="margin-left:190px;margin-right:auto; margin-top:45px; font-size:20px;">
<tr>
<th><a class="navbar" href="PupLove.html">Home</a></th>
<th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveDonate.html">Donate</a></th>
<th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveCare.html">How to take care of a dog</a></th>
<th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveContacts&FAQ's.html">Contacts and FAQ's</a></th>
<th><a class="navbar" href="PupLoveBlog.html">Blog</a></th>
</tr>
</table>
</nav>

<div><a href="PupLoveNala.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:50px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://www.yourpurebredpuppy.com/dogbreeds/photos-EFGH/goldenretrieversf1.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
<a class="name" style="margin-left:50px;" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveNala.html">Nala <br><br> Breed: Golden <br> Retriever <br><br> Sex: Female</a></div>

<div><a href="PupLoveBillie.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:350px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://www.yourpurebredpuppy.com/dogbreeds/photos-EFGH/greatdanesf5.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
<a class="name" style="margin-left:350px; padding:36.5px" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveBillie.html">Billie <br><br> Breed: Great <br> Dane <br><br> Sex: Male</a></div>

<div><a href="PupLoveBendi.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:650px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://www.yourpurebredpuppy.com/dogbreeds/photos-AB/australiancattledogsf1.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
<a class="name" style="margin-left:650px; padding:41px" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveBendi.html">Bendi <br><br> Breed: Blue <br> Heeler <br><br> Sex: Male</a></div>

<div><a href="PupLoveRufus.html"><img style="position:absolute; margin-top:60px; margin-left:950px; border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Bearded_collie_and_a_rope.jpg/640px-Bearded_collie_and_a_rope.jpg" height="300" width="200"></a>
<a class="name" style="margin-left:950px; padding:21px" href="file:///C:/Users/del0044/OneDrive/HTML%20Coding/PupLove/PupLoveRufus.html"><br>Rufus <br><br> Breed: Bearded <br> Collie <br><br> Sex: Male<br>ㅤ</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed the tags to be the same as what you posted but the CSS still seems to not work. I think it might be something to do with the file. Are there any specific things which are 'dont's' for saving html files?